# Passing Parameters between forms and context

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am switching the user database on the login screen however I am coming across a problem entity is only remembering when it first got the connection which I set to an empty db.

```
 public int DatabaseSelected { get; set; }
 public SourceContext()
    {
        if (DatabaseSelected == 0)
        {
            myUser.MyDatabase = 0;//LETS DEFAULT TO THE FIRST DB ON STARTUP.

        }
           SourceDatabases selectedDb = (SourceDatabases)DatabaseSelected;

        string connstring = SetupConnections(selectedDb);


            this.Connectionstring = _connstring;

  }
```

In my login screen I allow the user to change the db.

[image]

Now as well all no entity requires a database for access so I made a blank db called empty db the same structure but without client data.

The problem I am now facing is how do I tell Entity Framework to force the reset without. I have a property called

```
public int DatabaseSelected { get; set; }
```

Which is shared throughout my code and then when I get to my context I am going through and setting the database up here:

```
    public string SetupConnections(SourceDatabases database)
    {
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder efBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        try
        {

            string metaData = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
            string initialcatalog = "";
            const string appName = "EntityFramework";
            const string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            if (database == 0)//entity framework needs a default blank database to work with as the first call to this context will be on login.
            {

                initialcatalog = "EMPTYDB";
            }
            if (database == SourceDatabases.COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }
        if (database == SourceDatabases.COASTALVISIONCARE)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALVISIONCARE";
        }
        if (database == SourceDatabases.ELEANORSAHN)
        {
            initialcatalog = "ELEANORSAHN";
        }

        if (database == SourceDatabases.GLAUCOMACONSULTANTS)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }

        if (database == SourceDatabases.MARIANNEROSEN)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }
        const string dataSource = "sourcenet";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = initialcatalog;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "scheduler";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "BORG8472";
        sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = appName;


        efBuilder.Metadata = metaData;
        efBuilder.Provider = providerName;
        efBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;


            using (EntityConnection conn =
                new EntityConnection(efBuilder.ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {

        }
        return efBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

But for some reason it's always sitting at the emptydb connection string. I know most applications usually restart and place this value in a ini file but in 2018 is that the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot answer why you can't pass parameters between your form and code since you have provided no code samples about that, I can try to direct you into [the correct way of handling multiple contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) without headaches.

The above link explains it in an ASP.NET project, however the point still stands.

To start with, you need to have an interface which is basicly a contract between your database schemas. When you need to change the database, you can inject the context deriving from that interface.

This way, you can just use that interface's reference in your code, and query that from your repository.

I strongly recommend you to restructure your infrastructure, it can quickly get out of hand in the future where your projects grows and becomes more complex.